# How to use new OCLC Classify API in python with OAuth?

Tags: python, endpoint

I really appreciate this community. I am a librarian at a public university in Canada trying to use an API to help other librarians track ebooks that we purchase.

I had been using the OCLC Classify API quite successfully in my python code until they changed it, and how they changed it is beyond what I understand. It is explained a little here:
https://www.oclc.org/developer/api/oclc-apis/classify.en.html
and
https://www.oclc.org/developer/api/oclc-apis/classify/classification.en.html

I have arranged a client ID and client_secret with OCLC (aka a "WSKey") but do not understand what I need to put in my python code to use them.
Using their example, what do I need to do in python before making the URL request for:
https://metadata.api.oclc.org/classify/?oclc=57358293&summary=true
in order to get results rather than what I get in my browser, which is:
{"message":"Unauthorized"}
(I also used to be able to test my API URLs directly in my browser while working on my code.)

I don't have any python code yet to who you because I don't know what they even mean by "secure endpoint".

Thank you for any help you can provide!

PS: What I'm really trying to do is get the OCLC number (known in the library world as the OCN) for a given ISBN, but via python because I have a file with a long list of ISBNs, so not appropriate to just use their web-based interactive version, which is here:
http://classify.oclc.org/classify2/api_docs/classify.html

Comment: I don't use OCLC, but as it appears to use OAuth going by its API Key [registration page](https://www.oclc.org/developer/api/keys.en.html). My guess is that you'll likely have to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43965495/python-requests-to-access-oauth-website-content-snl-finance

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have resolved this but I asked their support and you now need to include the key in the headers like so:

```
headers = {'X-OCLC-API-Key': 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID_WSKEY'}
params = {'oclc': '6388846', 'summary' : 'false', 'maxRecs':100}
# or use 'isbn' or 'stn

r = requests.get('https://metadata.api.oclc.org/classify/', params=params,headers=headers)

print(r.text)
```